# Is there a function for rad2deg and deg2rad for use in pst-solides3d?

Tags: pstricks, postscript, pst-solides3d

Basically I'm using `pst-solides3d` to produce 3d-perspective figures. When writing the 3d transform parameters for `rotateOpoint3d`, it is required to have a unit of **degree**. But when writing an argument for `Sin` and `Cos` functions in `PostScript®`, a unit of **rad** is required. This is where  **rad2deg** and **deg2rad** functions come in handy. For example,

```
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
...
\psSolid[object=cylindre,h=1,r=.1,fillcolor=yellow,
ngrid=1 32,linewidth=.5pt,
transform={<some-angle-in-radian> <imaginary function for rad2deg> 0 0 rotateOpoint3d}]%
```

So I checked up **PostScript® LANGUAGE REFERENCE** but cannot find these commands. I could always do it with elementary operations but it would be cumbersome. **So my question is:**`Does anyone know the existence or non-existence of such functions in PostScript or pst-solides3d?`

Comment: Could you provide some example code that puts your questions into a TeX/LaTeX context? As of now, your posting may be off-topic for this site since it appears to be primarily about PostScript.

Comment: No, but some functions are defined in the algebraic parser already, which is described in `pst-news08.pdf` and other documents.

Comment: Pstricks defines the `\degrees` command that sets angle units to degrees, and `\radians`, which is the same as `\degrees[6.28319]`. Actually, you can have any unit for angles. See §4, pp. 7-8 of pstricks documentation.

Comment: And you will find some examples about how `[algebraic]` option is used in the `pst-solides3d` document.

Comment: @LeoLiu Thanks, but I am uncomfortable with `[algebraic]` style...

Comment: @Bernard That function does not work in postscript context.

Comment: @Mico On the contrary, this is quite a `pst-solides3d` question and therefore not off-topic.

Comment: @Mico But if Postscript irritates people like you, I can remove it from the title at least.

Comment: Your posting became a lot more on-topic for this site after you posted some actual code, as I had suggested. By the way, why do you surmise that Postscript would "irritate people like me"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The procedures `Sin` and `Cos` aren't native PostScript operators, but are defined in `pst-solides3d.pro` as:

```
/Cos {rd cos} def
/Sin {rd sin} def
```

with

```
/pi 3.14159 def
/rd {180 pi div mul} def
```

The native PostScript operators are `sin` and `cos` and take their argument in degrees.

If you want to specify an angle in radians which should be used by `rotateOpoint3d`, use `rd`, which is specified in `pst-solides3d.pro`:

```
\psSolid[object=cylindre,h=1,r=.1,fillcolor=red,
ngrid=1 32,linewidth=.5pt,
transform={<some-angle-in-radian> rd 0 0 rotateOpoint3d}]%
```

Comment: Oh, quite strange, because I tried `sin` and `cos` but it failed to generate the solids (although the compilation is successful).

Comment: And thank you. I upvoted, but I didnt accept it since it does not fully address my question.

Comment: I updated the answer: just use `rd` to transform your `angle-in-radians` in degrees.